# What to do with questions without any answers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, self-answer

I have an [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975895/possible-to-use-referencemap-with-join-on-zend-db-select) on Stack Overflow. It has no answers, not even a comment.

What should I do with it? Delete it or answer it myself? At the [Danish "ExpertExchange"](http://www.exp.dk) the procedure is to answer the question yourself.

Comment: If you want to get attention for the question, see the strategies at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions.

Comment: Start a bounty !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the answer, you should definitely answer it.  It's encouraged on SO.

You can edit the question with more information, or to word it better and it will bump the question on the Active page.

You can add a bounty to put it on the featured page and draw interest, this is a very effective technique.

[Official Take Here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: "And since it's your own answer and you verified it also mark it accepted"

Comment: I don't know the answer :) Think the danish reference confuses here.. "the procedure is to answer the question yourself." is just ment as a procedure to close (or abandon) the question.

Comment: @Phl, ahh, I see.  Then you should leave the question out there, and if you can think of more details, or a better way to describe it, then do so, and it will bump the post on the Active page.  Also of course you can add a bounty to it to bring it more attention.